# Global Exception handler that returns same as InternalServerError(ex)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a few controllers. Each one has a few methods. Each method has a try/catch block that contains the same thing:

```cs
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
```

This returns the exception information as json, which is what I need. I'm pretty sure it's just the exception object serialized as json.

What I would like to do is have a global exception handler so I can get rid of all the try / catch blocks and clean up my controllers.

Here's the catch. The samples I've seen don't return what I need to return. That's why I think this is not a duplicate.

Here's my code for those who want to see it.

```cs
public class GlobalExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler

{
    public Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        //HttpResponseMessage response =
        //                            new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        //response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(con);
        //response.RequestMessage = Request;
        //return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I found the right [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling), it turned out to be easy:

```cs
public class GlobalExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler

{
    public Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, context.Exception.Message));
    }
}
```